# PHP: How to get a value from XML and multiply it?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have a script that has been written by a former developer.
The script get values from a XML file and send them to a `mysql` database.

There is the following line:

```
$data['price'] = (int)($row->{get($row, 'PRIX')}->PRIX ? $row->{get($row, 'PRIX')}->PRIX : $row->{get($row, 'LOYER')}->LOYER);
```

This command gets values from `LOYER` or `PRIX` fields and export it to the `price` field in the database.

I would like to multiply the value export. The calculation should be:
price=PRIX (or LOYER) * 300

But I don't know how to edit the command line.

Thanks.

Comment: A calc in php or mysql code?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand :

```
$data['price'] = (int)($row->{get($row, 'PRIX')}->PRIX ? $row->{get($row, 'PRIX')}->PRIX : $row->{get($row, 'LOYER')}->LOYER);
if(is_numeric($data['price'])){
$data['price']) = $data['price']) * 300;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as above, but fixed the code/typo inside the logic.

```
$data['price'] = (int)($row->{get($row, 'PRIX')}->PRIX ? $row->{get($row, 'PRIX')}->PRIX : $row->{get($row, 'LOYER')}->LOYER);

if(is_numeric($data['price'])){
    $data['price'] = $data['price'] * 300;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working. However, the real multiplicator I have to use is 119.33 instead of 300. And when I execute the script, it doesn't work then. Any idea why?

Comment: @user3301061 There is no reason why changing the number should break it.  Something else is happening..

Comment: @user3301061 "doesn't work" is not helpful at all. Apply some basic debugging techniques to your code, narrow down the problem and edit your question with specifics, so we can support you.

Comment: I think I did a mistake, because after several test, the correct data was imported. Thanks guys!